# Codeigniter alphabetical menu

Tags: codeigniter, menu, alphabetical

I want to create simple alphabetical menu, and things look like I'm close to what I want but I have to remove duplicate letters:

in model I use:

```
public function svi_izvodjaci_za_izbornik()
{
    $this->db->order_by('naziv', 'ASC');

    $query = $this->db->get('izvodjac');

    return $query->result();
}
```

in controller I use:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['izvodjaci_za_izbornik'] = $this->pocetak_model->svi_izvodjaci_za_izbornik();

    $this->load->view('zaglavlje');
    $this->load->view('pocetak', $data);
    $this->load->view('podnozje');
}
```

in view I use:

```
<?php foreach ($izvodjaci_za_izbornik as $izvodjac_za_izbornik): ?>

<a href="#"><?php echo mb_substr($izvodjac_za_izbornik->naziv, 0, 1, 'utf-8'); ?></a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and the result is:

[image: menu]

Also I plan to pass that letter to controller method who will then call model method that looks something like this:

```
public function izvodjaci_abecedno($letter)
{
    $this->db->like('naziv', $letter, 'after');
    $query = $this->db->get('izvodjac');

    return $query->result(); 
}
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Why are you loading a menu from your database? menus are pretty static in nature, I would suggest just coding them, perhaps storing them directly into an object and creating an instance of that object when you're looking to use it... this way you only edit 1 file that contains all menus...

Comment: yeah, when i think about it makes sense, let me try it like that, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Remove duplicate alphabets like this.use `$this->db->distinct();`

In your **Model**

```
  <?php
 public function svi_izvodjaci_za_izbornik()
    {
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select('naziv');//if you nedd to select more columns name seperate by comma like col1,col2,col3,..
        $this->db->from('izvodjac');
        $this->db->order_by('naziv', 'ASC');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: thanky ou, if i understand this removes duplicate walues in column "naziv", but i dont have duplicates there it's just values starting with same letter, so i need to filter "distinct" only first letter not whole value of column "naziv". Hope i got it right